# insert into table using union of views causing issues

Tags: sql, sql-server, view, insert, union

I am trying to insert data into a temp table by doing union of view but i am getting following error.What could be the reason for it. When i do normal select the query runs fine.

> Query processor could not produce a query plan because of the hints
>   defined in this query. Resubmit the query without specifying any hints
>   and without using SET FORCEPLAN.

```
insert into #temp
SELECT 'aaa', COUNT(*) FROM view1
 UNION
 SELECT 'bbb', COUNT(*) FROM view2
 UNION
 SELECT 'ccc', COUNT(*) FROM view3
 UNION
 SELECT 'ddd', COUNT(*) FROM view4
 UNION
 SELECT 'eee', COUNT(*) FROM view5
 UNION
 SELECT 'fff', COUNT(*) FROM view6
 UNION
 SELECT 'ggg', COUNT(*) FROM view7
 UNION
 SELECT 'hhh', COUNT(*) FROM view8
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? BTW, I'd do `UNION ALL`  here, since there are no duplicates to remove.

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server..Using UNION ALL is going to resolve the issue?.

Comment: UNION ALL was a general advice. The error message clearly says "_Resubmit the query without specifying any hints and without using SET FORCEPLAN._"

Answer (score 1):

What you have written should work. Check for 2 things. Since it is a temporary table, check if removing any view from the UNION of views fixes it. Then, check that view individually. Script all your views and check if any of those use hints like NOLOCK, EXPAND etc. and which one is causing the problem.

Also, you can try writing it like this

```
insert into #temp
SELECT field, total FROM 
 (SELECT 'aaa' field, COUNT(*) total FROM view1
 UNION
 SELECT 'bbb', COUNT(*) FROM view2
 UNION
 SELECT 'ccc', COUNT(*) FROM view3
 UNION
 SELECT 'ddd', COUNT(*) FROM view4
 UNION
 SELECT 'eee', COUNT(*) FROM view5
 UNION
 SELECT 'fff', COUNT(*) FROM view6
 UNION
 SELECT 'ggg', COUNT(*) FROM view7
 UNION
 SELECT 'hhh', COUNT(*) FROM view8) Z
```